# How to change the label format of a list

Tags: table-of-contents, lists

I'm using tcolorbox theorems in my project. I had to create a list for them as below:

[image]

Each entry in the "List of Definitions" is in the format:

```
COUNTER SPACE NAME .......
1   Cat ........
2   Dog ........
```

I need to change the label to be as:

```
DEFINITION COUNTER DASH NAME .......
Definition 1 - Cat ........
Definition 2 - Dog ........
```

How can I do that?
A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{abntex2}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}


%  Definition
\newcommand{\definitionname}{Definition}
\newcommand{\listofdefinitionsname}{List of Definitions}
\newtcbtheorem[list inside={lod}]{definition}{Definition}{colback=black!5,colframe=white!35!black}{th}

\newlistof{listofdefinitions}{lod}{\listofdefinitionsname}
\newlistentry{definition}{lod}{0}

\begin{document}

% Definitions
\pdfbookmark[0]{\listofdefinitionsname}{lod}
\listofdefinitions*

\begin{definition}{Cat}{}
Cat is an animal
\end{definition}

Some text

\begin{definition}{Dog}{}
Dog is an animal
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I take it \newlistof is peculiar to abntex2?

Comment: @JohnKormylo It is a tocloft package command. But you can use another one